# How to stash individual files with magit

Tags: magit

git is capable of stashing of individual hunks.

> With `--patch`, you can interactively select hunks from the diff between **HEAD** and the working tree to be stashed. The stash entry is constructed such that its index state is the same as the index state of your repository, and its worktree contains only the changes you selected interactively. The selected changes are then rolled back from your worktree. See the *“Interactive Mode”* section of *git-add[1]* to learn how to operate the `--patch` mode.

Is it possible to use it with magit frontend? Magit simplifies patch mode usage for staging spectacular. Could it do the same work for stashes?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can stage whatever changes you want to stash and then call magit-stash-index (zi).

Comment: It seems to be difficult to keep renamed files out of the staging, though. (But I am not a git expert.)

Comment: If I only stage part of the change in a file and `zi`, the staged part of the change will be in unstaged status.

Answer (score 1):

`magit-stash-index` (zi) and `magit-stash-worktree` (zw) work well if you can easily sequester what you want to stash into an otherwise empty index or worktree. When that's not the case, I use `magit-git-topdir` (!!) to run a command like:

```
git stash push -m "my stash title" my/file1 my/file2
```

I just raised a [feature request](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/4583) to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use:

```
 magit-stash-push
```

Which has an individual files option  `--`.